# CKSubscriptions and production container

Tags: swift, icloud

Hi I'm trying to create a CKSubscription, I use this code:

```
func setupCKSubscriptions(){

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("sub") == false{

    let subscription = CKSubscription(recordType: "Quadri", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: .FiresOnRecordCreation)

    let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
    notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = NSLocalizedString("NEW_Q", comment: "")
    notificationInfo.shouldBadge = true

    subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

    CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.saveSubscription(subscription) { (subscription, errore) -> Void in

        if errore == nil{

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "sub")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Ok", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }else{

            print(errore?.localizedDescription)
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Errore", message: errore?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    }else{

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Errore", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The problem is that this code only works on the simulator, when I run the app on a real device I get this error:

> attempting to create a subscription in a production container.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and the solution is easy, BUT NOT VERY INTUITIVE.
In development mode let the app create the subscription(s) you need. Deploy database to production.
Test your app in production and you'll see it can now create the subscription you have made.
Hope it works

Comment: To complement this answer (as it was not very clear for me at first): When you create a subscription while developing it will be recorded on the CloudKit Dashboard. After the subscription is created it will appear under Dashboard > Container > Development > Schema > Subscription Types. As mentioned in the answer the next step is to deploy the Schema to Production.

Comment: Yes.For some reason the subscription has to be created in development, and then deployed to production.